# What is the official explanation of why the spin-1 $W^{\pm}$ Bosons having a magnetic moment?

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-spin, standard-model, magnetic-moment, electroweak

How is it possible a spin-1 particle to ever have a magnetic moment?

Is there any analytical solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The W bosons have magnetic moments according to the fact that they have a spin and are charged. Indeed in the standard model there is an interaction term of the form:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{WW\gamma}=-ieF_{\mu \nu} W^{+,\mu} W^{-,\nu}
\end{equation}
Where $F$ is the Faraday tensor, and $W^+$ and $W^-$ are the fields associated to the bosons. This term can be rewritten as:
\begin{equation}
-ie \partial_\mu (W^{+,\mu}W^{-,\nu}-W^{-,\mu}W^{+,\nu})A_\nu
\end{equation}
Which resembles a lot to the corresponding term in QED for fermions : $-\frac{e}{2m}\partial_\mu(\overline{\Psi} \sigma^{\mu \nu} \Psi)A_\nu$. In fact, and according to the article ["How Large is the “Natural” Magnetic
Moment?"](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0607187) eq. (22), this interaction term leads to:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{WW\gamma}\leadsto-\frac{e}{2m}\partial_i \epsilon^{ijk}\langle f | S_k | i \rangle A_j
\end{equation}
Which is indeed of the form of a magnetic momentum.

Comment: Lesson learned: As long you have a combination of non-zero charge and non-zero spin you have a magnetic moment.

Comment: Nevertheless, neutrinos don't have charge, only spin but still have a magnetic moment. So I guess this rule of thumb is not general.

Comment: @Markoul11 Neutrinos don't have magnetic moment per se, there's only one because of the electroweak model allowing a loop W/lepton that can be attached to a photon and an incoming and an outgoing neutrino.

Comment: I disagree. Their magnetic moment is analytically proven (2.1 section, [https://tinyurl.com/hv64n884]  and the upper limit of the magnetic moment experimentally defined at $\mu_{\nu}<2 \times 10^{-11} \mu_{B}$. They have so much small tiny magnetic moment  because their so tiny mass which is also priori in order a particle to have a magnetic moment.

Comment: @Markoul11 see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/381885/do-neutrinos-have-magnetic-moment) the answer of Chris. As I said, neutrinos have a magnetic moment only due to loop diagrams, not due to their nature. Since there's no photon/neutrino/antineutrino vertex in the SM, they can't have a "bare" magnetic moment.

Comment: As Dirac also disputed https://www.mediatheque.lindau-nobel.org/videos/31423/electrons-and-the-vacuum-1956 the bare model of particles is not a physical model but a mathematical convention anyway, The mass of a particle is dressed with quantum field excitation. The $\alpha_{W}=10^{-6}$ electroweak coupling constant defines the manifold of this excitation which can be several meters in de Broglie wavelength due its tiny mass.

Comment: The chargeless tiny mass is the intrinsic physical reason the spin 1/2  neutrinos must and do have a magnetic moment and not due an extrinsic interaction. It is not possible by definition IMO a spin 1/2 elementary massive particle not to have an intrinsic magnetic moment.

Comment: Of course, the bare model is a mathematical convenience. I don't know if you already have done any QFT calculation, but you seem to think that the magnetic moment is an intrinsic property of massive charged particles - this is wrong: it is something that only has sense thanks to the photon field. I think you misunderstand me when I talk about particles. What I mean by this word is "the mathematical object used in perturbative expansion". In the case of neutrinos, these are spinors.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of the spin is a intrinsic magnetic moment.

Comment: Correction: For 1/2 spin, not for spin 1.